# Как отобразить коллекцию как значение в DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, xaml

Есть `DataGrid`, `ItemsSource` которого является `List<Author>`. В классе Author есть публичное свойство `List<Book>`. У класса Book переопределён метод `ToString()`. При отображении `DataGrid` в колонка `books` заполняется значениями `(List<Book>).ToString()` т.е. получается значение `(Collection)`. Хочу, чтобы в ячейках колонки `Books` навпротив каждого автора было значение типа `String.Join("\r\n", books)` или в эту ячейку вставить `ListView` и установить есть `ItemsSource` как `Books`. Но я не знаю как это реализовать. Можете помочь?

Comment: Если вам надо как то по особенному коллекцию в строку превратить при биндинге, используйте конвертеры.

Comment: @tym32167 спасибо